# Сокращения в php

Tags: phpmyadmin

Есть провевка отсутствия хотя бы одной переменной вида:

```
if (!$perem1 || !$perem2 || !$perem3 || !$perem4 || !$perem5 || !$perem6 || !$perem7) {...}
```

Запись напрашивается на сокращение. А как же её можно сократить?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

http://php.su/functions/?isset

```
if(!isset($var1, $var2, $var3)){
// code
}
```